# Merge UV changes from .fbx file back into Maya

Tags: python, maya, mel

I am trying to export a `FBX` model from Maya, modify some of the UVs externally, and then reimporting it back to Maya, replacing just the portions that have been changed.

To export:

```
cmds.file(myFile, type='FBX', exportSelected=True, lf=False, f=True)
```

To import:

```
cmds.file(myFile, i=True, type='FBX', ra=True, mnc=True, pr=True, lf=False, f=True)
```

However, after running the commands, nothing changed within the scene. How do I merge and overwrite the current scene with the new changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.file(myFile, typ='FBX', es=True, lf=False, f=True)
```

Your options need to be passed via MEL evals if you’re using Python:

```
import maya.mel as mel

mel.eval('FBXResetExport; 
          FBXExportInputConnections -v false; 
          FBXExportBakeComplexAnimation -v true; 
          FBXExportLights -v false; 
          FBXExportCameras -v false; 
          FBXExportInAscii -v true; 
          FBXExportFileVersion FBX201200; 
          FBXExportSmoothingGroups -v false; 
          FBXExportSmoothMesh -v false; 
          FBXExportApplyConstantKeyReducer -v false; 
          FBXExportBakeComplexAnimation -v true;  
          FBXExportBakeComplexStep -v 1;  
          FBXExportCameras -v false;’
        )
```

**P.S. This is an example how your code might look like**.